# What is the total number of symbols obtained?

Tags: combinatorics

A certain organization has established a code system in which symbols are formed by one or more points, up to a maximum of 6 points, arranged so as to occupy the vertices and midpoints of the longest sides of a rectangle. What is the total number of symbols obtained?

The answer's book: $2^6-1$

My answer: $6+6*5+6*5*4+6*5*4*3+6*5*4*3*2+6*5*4*3*2*1$, beacuse first you choose 1 out of 6 possible points for the symbol with a point, added to the case of 2-point symbols where you first choose 6 possible points and the other 5 possible remaining points, and so on until the case where you have 6 points chosen... but apparently my thinking is wrong, what's wrong with my count and why's $2^6-1$ is the correct answer?

Comment: The vertices and midpoints of the *longest sides* of a rectangle only give $6$ points, if the rectangle isn't square.

Comment: Apparently you were thinking that the order in which vertices are chosen makes a difference.  The book answer is treating the chosen vertices as a *set*, i.e. without regard to their order.

Comment: @saulspatz thank you for the correction, but the thought I used to solve the question still wrong...

Comment: @hardmath How can I find out whether or not an order in an issue matters? In case the question is about allocating people in chairs the order always matters, I thought by this analogy to this question...

Comment: @Dorta People are always distinguishable, but geometric points are not.

Comment: Perhaps a citation of the book (title, author) where this problem is found (chapter or page) would help clear up whether the order that points are selected maters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each point might or might not be in the set.  That gives $2^6$ possibilities.  But that includes the empty set,so we have to subtract that.

The problem with your method is double-counting.  You're right that there are $6$ one-point possibilities, but you're wrong when you say there are $6\cdot5$ two-point possibilities.  You count choosing point A and then choosing point B and also choosing point B and then choosing point A, but these result in the same code.

If you adjust for the order of choosing, you get
$$6+\frac{6\cdot5}{2!}+\frac{6\cdot5\cdot4}{3!}+\frac{6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3}{4!}+\frac{6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2}{5!}+\frac{6!}{6!}=63
$$